# why does the output varies for same input

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
void fun(int *, int size, int *, int *new_size);

int main()
{
    int size, new_size;                            // variables declaration
    printf("Enter the size : ");                   // prompting user to enter the size of the array
    scanf("%d", &size);                            // reading size from the user
    int arr[size], arr1[size];                     // declaring array of size
    printf("Enter the elements into the array: "); // prompt the user to enter the elements of array
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", arr + i); // reading the elements of array from user
    }
    fun(arr, size, arr1, &new_size);       // calling function
    printf("After removing duplicates: "); // prompting user a new array after removing duplicates
    for (int i = 0; i < new_size; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", arr1[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("before removing duplicates: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

}
void fun(int *arr, int size, int *arr1, int *new_size) // function definition
{
    int count = 1; // declaring variables
    arr1[0] = arr[0];

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        int flag = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        {
            if (arr[i] == arr1[j])
            {
                break;
            }
            flag = flag + 1;
            if (arr1[flag] == 0)
            {
                *(arr1+flag) = arr[i];
                count = count + 1;
            }
        }
         
    }
    *new_size = count;
   
}
```

basically what i am doing is, getting the array elements and removing duplicates elements and assigning non-duplicate elements to new array,while without modifying the old array and displaying new array with modification, old array without modification.
But the problem is when i execute this code the output varies for same input values. Why is that i couldn't figure it out.
Here is the output of the program.

```
Enter the size : 5
Enter the elements into the array: 5
1
2
1
2
After removing duplicates: 5 1 2 
before removing duplicates: 5 1 2 1 2
```

```
Enter the size : 5
Enter the elements into the array: 5
4
3
2
1
After removing duplicates: 5 4 3 2 1 
before removing duplicates: 5 4 3 2 1
```

```
Enter the size : 5
Enter the elements into the array: 5
1
2
1
2
After removing duplicates: 5 1 6 
before removing duplicates: 5 1 2 1 2
```

see the output changes

Comment: Did run your code in a **debugger** to see where that error occurs, then run it again with a breakpoint near that failure so you can step carefully ahead and watch what happens leading up to that point?

Comment: original array remains same that is stored in `arr[]` but in `arr1[]` duplicate elements are removed.

Comment: The code in `main` looks fine. The code in `fun`, not so much. I have no idea what you're trying to do there.

Comment: @tadman i am a beginner i don't how to use debugger properly, i used gdb but couldn't figure it out

Comment: The code copies the first element to the output array. So the `i` loop should start with `int i = 1;`. And the `j` loop should just check if `arr[i]` is already in the output array. So that should be `for (int j = 0; j < count; j++)`. **After** the `j` loop finishes, the code should decide whether to add `arr[i]` to the output array.

Comment: I get that it can be a little bewildering at first, but it gives you incredible insight into what your code is actually doing, and can help you find problems way more quickly than just bashing around aimlessly. GDB is certainly a capable debugger, but there are others far more friendly to use, or you can find a front-end for it that makes it a lot more user-friendly.

Comment: @user3386109   in `fun` i stored 0^th index element in `arr1[]` and i take this array `arr1[]` compare it with original array i.e., `arr[]` if the element matches in both the array i break the loop, if not  i will increment the flag variable i use this flag  as index reference and check whether in `arr1[]` is 0 or non-zero value if it is 0, then i assign the `arr1[]`=`arr[]` so this is how i remove duplicate elements. I hope it is understandable.

Comment: @user3386109 can you explain it once again i did not understand

Comment: I think `fun` should be named `deduplicate_copy`? Or is it deduplicating, or making a set?

Comment: For each element `a[i]` in the input array, check if it's already in the output array with code like `int dup=0; for(int j=0;j<count;j++) {if (arr[i] == arr[j]){dup=1; break;}` If `a[i]` isn't already in the output array, add it.